# How to get a work permit for Canada from Malaysia (Indian passport holder)?

Tags: working-visas, canada, indian-citizens

I am working in Sutherland Global Services (BPO) as an IT consultant. Is there any way to get a work permit for Canada?

I am a graduate with commerce and had 5 years experience in financial services back in India and now 3 years here in BPO.

Please suggest something reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the official Citizenship and Immigration Canada web pages on this, e.g., http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/permit.asp ?

The answer to your question depends a lot on whether you want to work in Canada temporarily (for 2 years, can be extended to 4 years, search for Work Permit) or permanently (search for Permanent Residency). Note that it is possible to get a temporary Work Permit and to apply for Permanent Residency later, after you've "tried out" Canada and you decided you want to stay.